# Sentence in a poem - The penalty by Neil Rollinson

Tags: sentence-meaning

I'm not quite sure the meaning of a sentence:

> "You take a run, you are running all day and night"

in a poem - The Penalty by Neil Rollinson.

Comment: To take a run is to go for a run, usually for exercise. It could also mean a run in baseball. Without the context of the poem, I can't say what the meaning is, and even with the context, poetry is not always easy to decipher.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In his poem [***The Penalty***](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=UZ6mBZdQ3UEC&pg=PT6&lpg=PT6&dq=%22You+take+a+run,+you+are+running+all+day+and+night%22&source=bl&ots=QqosFAIIgw&sig=an0aaC0EduT-Yn_XzhEzOoKJ7Kk&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwjQx4bmxu_KAhUK7xQKHayoBeoQ6AEILDAC#v=onepage&q=%22You%20take%20a%20run%2C%20you%20are%20running%20all%20day%20and%20night%22&f=false), Neil Rollinson is describing taking a [**penalty kick**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Penalty_kick) from **it's spot**. The penalty ball spot is located 11 meters from the goal line.

It is a **one-on-one** situation between the kicker and the goalie and is a **free kick** without any other opposition.

**Penalty kicks** are high drama in **football** (BrE, soccer (AmE)) matches.

The description

> **You take a run, you are running all day and night**

refers to the approach the kicker takes towards the ball before kicking it. (S)he is **only allowed to move in a forward direction** and is not allowed to move forward then backup and move forward again in order to fake out the goalie.

The emotion the author is expressing is that it **seems to take forever** to get to the ball when in reality the ball is only a few strides away. Such is the drama of a penalty kick. So the description is poetic.

Penalty kicks are used to resolve games that en in a draw (even score) but where someone must win.  These can be called **penalty shoot outs**.

Examples of a penalty kick by Ronaldo is [**here**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LtPMpH7ShmQ), some funny ones are [**here**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=xfLmmRS7eiY) and an example of a shootout is [**here**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3B0TCrZo9I0)